# run a windows scheduler task once other tasks have finished

Tags: xpath, scheduled-tasks, eventtrigger

I have 5 tasks set up in the windows task scheduler.
Tasks A,B,C and D run at the same time each day in parallel. These all run absolutely fine.

I want task E to run each day once tasks A and B and C and D have all finished. This is the one I am having trouble with.

I have researched and found a number of promising links which show how to set up a custom event trigger:

[running a scheduled task after another](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davethompson/2011/10/25/running-a-scheduled-task-after-another/)

[trigger event on multiple different previous events success](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/14841f8f-0e5a-4176-b789-28ac62db6c90/task-scheduler-trigger-event-on-multiple-different-previous-events-success?forum=winserverManagement)

[custom event filter trigger is not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206721/task-scheduler-custom-event-filter-trigger-is-not-triggering-action)

I have tried countless different combinations of XML without success. Either task E does not get triggered, or it gets triggered continuously. I have tried so many combinations I am not sure which ones I should post on here (ie which ones are "closest" and would be helpful). I will post 1 below - if anyone requires other variations then I will post those too.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    *[
    @Event[
        @EventData[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TaskA']
        and 
        @System[@TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;=3600000]]
         ]

        and

    @Event[
        @EventData[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TaskB']
        and 
        @System[@TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;=3600000]]
         ]

    and

    @Event[
        @EventData[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TaskC']
        and 
        @System[@TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;=3600000]]
         ]

    and

    @Event[
        @EventData[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TaskD']
        and 
        @System[@TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;=3600000]]
         ]
     ]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this some more and didn't get anywhere, so I decided to solve the problem using a different approach.

I built a simple C# console app which would run tasks A,B,C and D in parallel. This app could then be called by a single task on the windows scheduler.

From there I could set a dependency in the scheduler for task E on the single scheduler task above by following the information on the links provided in my original post.

If someone does figure out a way to set up mutiple "AND" dependencies in the scheduler itself then it would be great to know how.